# pexpect not executing command by steps

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I have this Python3 code which use Pexpect.

```
import pexpect
import getpass
import sys

def ssh(username,password,host,port,command,writeline):
    child = pexpect.spawn("ssh -p {} {}@{} '{}'".format(port,username,host,command))
    child.expect("password: ")
    child.sendline(password)
    if(writeline):
        print(child.read())

def scp(username,password,host,port,file,dest):
    child = pexpect.spawn("scp -P {} {} {}@{}:{}".format(port,file,username,host,dest))
    child.expect("password: ")
    child.sendline(password)

try:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    print("=== sendhw remote commander ===")
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
    ssh(username,password,"some.host.net","22","mkdir ~/srakrnSRV",False)
    scp(username,password,"some.host.net","22",filename,"~/srakrnSRV")
    ssh(username,password,"some.host.net","22","cd srakrnSRV && sendhw {}".format(filename),True)

except IndexError:
    print("No homework name specified.")
```

My aim is to:

- SSH into the host with the `ssh` function, create the directory `srakrnSRV`, then
- upload a file into the `srakrnSRV` directory, which is previously created
- `cd` into `srakrnSRV`, and execute the `sendhw <filename>` command. The `filename` variable is defined by command line parameteres, and print the result out.

After running the entire code, Python prints out

```
b'\r\nbash: line 0: cd: srakrnSRV: No such file or directory\r\n'
```

which is not expected, as the directory should be previously created.

Also, I tried manually creating the `srakrnSRV` folder in my remote host. After running the command again, it appears that `scp` function is also not running. The only runnning pexpect coomand was the last `ssh` function.

How to make it execute in order? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may lack permission for executing commands through ssh. Also there is possibility that your program sends scp before prompt occurs.